# Copy one array into another in java. ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I am trying to copy a new array at the end of the one i have, but it keeps saying ArrayStoreException in the System.arraycopy and i dont know why, it should have space and everything.

this is the code:

```
objectzombie=zombieParser(result); /*give a 4 object array*/
GameObjectList arrayt= new GameObjectList(objectzombie.size()+this.objectlist.size());

System.arraycopy(objectzombie, 0, arrayt, 0, objectzombie.size());
System.arraycopy(this.objectlist, 0, arrayt, arrayt.size(), 
this.objectlist.size());
this.objectlist=arrayt;}
```

thank you for your help;

EDIT-------------

It looks like, i can't use the arraycopy if i don´t have a primitive array, how can i then combine my two lists? i don't know how could i do it.

Comment: please show the relevant code and the relevant stacktrace, you are showing way too little information

Comment: According to documentation: `Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayStoreException in java arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207155/arraystoreexception-in-java-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java SE API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), *Arguments* of `System.arraycopy` are:

- `src` - the source array.
- `srcPos` - starting position in the source array.
- `dest` - the destination array.
- `destPos` - starting position in the destination data.
- `length` - the number of array elements to be copied.

In the [method description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-), there is also:

> Otherwise, if any of the following is true, an ArrayStoreException is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>
> - The src argument refers to an object that is not an array.
> - The dest argument refers to an object that is not an array.
> - The src argument and dest argument refer to arrays whose component types are different primitive types.
> - The src argument refers to an array with a primitive component type and the dest argument refers to an array with a reference component type.
> - The src argument refers to an array with a reference component type and the dest argument refers to an array with a primitive component type.

the `src` and `dest` are **array**, whereas you tried to copy to target object of type `GameObjectList`, which is a mismatch => `ArrayStoreException`

Comment: I see, so i guess i can't use this. I will try to find another way then... but i cant think about one.

Comment: I modified the answer more clearly just now. You can read again to get to know how to use the core Java API :)

Comment: Thank you, but i nees to copy the arraylist one, so i guess i will have to use another thing